# Prove integral of second kind $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{e^{\sqrt x}-1}$ converges

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Here's the integral: $$\int\limits_0^1 \frac{dx}{e^{\sqrt x}-1}.$$ So far, I've unsuccessfully tried the comparison test. Got stuck with $$0<\frac 1 {e^{\sqrt x}-1}<\frac 1 {e^x-1}.$$ A hint would definitely help.

Comment: Use $e^w >1+w$ for $w>0$.

Comment: @Gary : Maybe you should post that as an answer.

Comment: General tip : Comparison is all about the leading term. You should figure out *where*, if anything, your function has trouble converging because it is blowing up, and find out how fast it's blowing up in terms of an easier function. This easier function is usually located using the Taylor series(in this case, the definition of $e^{\sqrt x}$). In this case, note that $e^{\sqrt x} - 1 = \sqrt x - \frac{x}{2!} + ...$, and you can easily prove either from here or using a standard result that $\frac{e^{\sqrt x} - 1}{\sqrt x} \to 1$ as $x \to 0$. So you must compare with $\frac 1{\sqrt x}$, now?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon it is $+x/2!$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Gary! It worked perfectly.

Comment: @Gary Oh yes, sorry about that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
$$
e^w =1+w+\frac{w^2}{2}+ \ldots \geq 1+w$$
for any $w\geq 0$, we have
$$
0 \le \int_0^1 {\frac{{dx}}{{e^{\sqrt x }  - 1}}}  \le \int_0^1 {\frac{{dx}}{{\sqrt x }}}  = 2,
$$
showing that the integral converges.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, as noticed in the comments, since as $x\to 0$ by standard limit we have

$$\frac{e^{\sqrt x}-1}{\sqrt x} \to 1$$

therefore the given integral converges by [limit comparison test](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ecbray/Stanford/2003-2004/Math%2042/limitcomp.pdf) with $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt x}$.

Comment: Maybe you could give the actual comparison to finish the answer please?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Sorry, what do you mean with "actual comparison"?

Comment: Please do the limit comparison test and not just state it?

Comment: @TymaGaidash LCT is in the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{\sqrt x}-1}{\sqrt x} = 1$ which assure that the given integral converges like $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt x}$. I've also given a reference for that. letme know what else is not sufficiently clear. Thanks